# Debug Mode vs Start without Debugging

Tags: c#, debugging

Every time I start the project without debugging i get the System.IO.FileNotFoundException, but when i just debug the code everything works perfect. 
Does anyone know anything about this problem? what can i do to solve this?

Here is the code:

```
        try
        {
            var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);
            fileContents = fileContents.Replace("?'", " ");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, fileContents);

            parser = new TextFieldParser(fileName);
            parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "'" };

            while (true)
            {
                segments = parser.ReadFields();
                if (segments == null)
                {
                    break;
                }         

                for (int i = 0; i < segments.Count(); ++i)
                {
                    if (segments[i] == "" || segments[i] == " ")
                    {
                        segments = segments.Except(new string[] {segments[i]}).ToArray();
                    }
                }
                    fillEdifactLetter(segments);                            
            }

            parser.Dispose();
            parser.Close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            if (e.Source != null)
                Console.WriteLine("IOException source: {0}", e.Source);
            throw;
        }
```

thanks, but it doesn't work..

the error message looks like:

Problemereignisname: CLR20r3

Problemsignatur 01: EdifactValidator.exe Problemsignatur 02: 1.0.0.0 Problemsignatur 03: 55c07efe Problemsignatur 04: mscorlib Problemsignatur 05: 4.0.30319.34014 Problemsignatur 06: 52e0b679 Problemsignatur 07: 451e Problemsignatur 08: ce Problemsignatur 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException Betriebsystemversion: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48 Gebietsschema-ID: 3079 Zusatzinformation 1: 5861 Zusatzinformation 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2 Zusatzinformation 3: a10f Zusatzinformation 4: a10ff7d2bb2516fdc753f9c34fc3b069

Maybe i have to add that the "fileName" is an absolut path...

Comment: Can you paste value of `fileName` ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the file exists in both `bin/Debug` and `bin/Release` folders.

If the file you are trying to access is in your source, you should probably edit the file properties in your solution - change `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer` or `Copy always`

Comment: what do you mean with: Compare the files in your bin/Debug and bin/Release folders below your solution. ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit simple/obvious but I have solved this before by doing a "clean" and then rebuilding again.